# Should a subquery on a join use tables from an outer query in the where clause?

Tags: sql, oracle, join, subquery

I need to add a subquery to a join, because one payment can have more than one allotment, so I only need to account for the first match (where rownum = 1).

However, I'm not sure if adding pmt from the outer query to the subquery on the allotment join is best.

Should I be doing this differently in the event of performance hits, etc.. ?

```
      SELECT
            pmt.payment_uid,
            alt.allotment_uid,

        FROM
            payment pmt

/* HERE: is the reference to pmt.pay_key and pmt.client_id 
   incorrect in the below subquery? */

            INNER JOIN allotment alc ON alt.allotment_uid = (
                SELECT
                    allotment_uid
                FROM
                    allotment
                WHERE
                        pay_key = pmt.pay_key
                    AND
                        pay_code = 'xyz'
                    AND
                        deleted = 'N'
                    AND
                        client_id = pmt.client_id
                    AND
                        ROWNUM = 1
            )

        WHERE

            AND
                pmt.deleted = 'N'
            AND
                pmt.date_paid >= TO_DATE('2017-07-01')
            AND
                pmt.date_paid < TO_DATE('2017-10-01') + 1;
```

Comment: Whether or not it's correct depends on what happens when you run it.

Comment: I'm dealing with large data, and the query is running very slow. I'm wondering if this may be contributing to slow performance - if this is something that should be avoided if possible...

Comment: The correlation in that subquery is quite probably causing slowness, and you cannot rely on rownum to give you"the first" unless you impose some deliberate order in the data. Is there a date or timestamp column in the allotment table e.g. a "date created"? (if so, what is the name of that column?)

Answer (score 0):

It's difficult to identify the performance issue in your query without seeing an explain plan output. You query does seem to do an additional SELECT on the allotment for every record from the main query.

Here is a version which doesn't use correlated sub query. Obviously I haven't been able to test it. It does a simple join in and then filters all records except one of the allotments. Hope this helps.

```
WITH v_payment
AS
(
     SELECT
            pmt.payment_uid,
            alt.allotment_uid,
            ROW_NUMBER () OVER(PARTITION BY allotment_id) r_num
        FROM
            payment pmt JOIN allotment alt
                          ON (pmt.pay_key = alt.pay_key AND
                              pmt.client_id = alt.client_id)
      WHERE pmt.deleted = 'N' AND
            pmt.date_paid >= TO_DATE('2017-07-01') AND
            pmt.date_paid < TO_DATE('2017-10-01') + 1 AND
            alt.pay_code = 'xyz' AND
            alt.deleted = 'N'
)
SELECT payment_uid,
       allotment_uid
  FROM v_payment
 WHERE r_num = 1;
```

Let's know how this performs!

Comment: the over clause needs an `order by`, but what column to use isn't absolutely clear

Comment: I used this, ordering by the allotment id. Can you explain why this is faster than using rownum = 1?

Comment: Correlated sub queries can result in the sub queries being executed for each record in the result set as opposed to only once. That can result in significant performance degradation. Having said the the Oracle in the recent days are clever enough to re-write most of the queries like them. It's difficult to say whether your original query suffered from this without looking at the explain plan. I would recommend you doing an explain plan of both versions and comparing the results.

Answer (score 0):

You can phrase the query that way.  I would be more likely to do:

```
SELECT . . .
FROM payment p INNER JOIN
     (SELECT a.*,
             ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY pay_key, client_id
                                ORDER BY allotment_uid
                               ) as seqnum
      FROM allotment a
      WHERE pay_code = 'xyz' AND deleted = 'N'
     ) a
     ON a.pay_key = p.pay_key AND a.client_id = p.client_id AND
        seqnum = 1
WHERE p.deleted = 'N' AND
      p.date_paid >= DATE '2017-07-01' AND
      p.date_paid < (DATE '2017-10-01') + 1;
```

Comment: Can you explain why this works much faster than using rownum = 1 in  the subquery?